# Interpreting tree classification errors in Matlab

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, cart, out-of-sample

I am currently using Matlab to generate random forests. I am using the `TreeBagger` class with the function `oobError`. I can plot a 2D figure which puts my tree count on the X-axis (IKA weak learners count) and classification error is on the Y-axis.

My question is: How can I interpret the actual error of my classifier (something like cross-validation which gives you a double as your classification error)?

Another question is: Is the X-axis of my figure the number of trees in bag or is it describing which tree (tree #50 for example) has the accuracy given at the corresponding point on the Y-axis?

Comment: what do you mean by "gives you a double"?  Are you referring to estimates of the two types of classification errors that can occur in a two-class problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing something like the example in the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/treebagger.html), then the plot contains the Out-Of-Bag Error as a function of the total number of trees.

If you want to cross-validate your model (which you should!), then build the TreeBagger object with some portion of your data and apply it the remaining held-out data with the predict() method. Matlab has a bunch of utility functions to make cross-validation easier. Take a look at the [cvpartition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/cvpartitionclass.html) class and the [crossval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/crossval.html) function, though it's obviously not too difficult to write your own versions either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I have read many articles and other stuff that the out of bag error is the real measure of the CCR in random forest. The k-fold cross validation method may not be suitable.

Comment: Interesting! Looking into this a little bit more, one can do even better by correcting the out-of-bar error rate, as in Bylander (2000) http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~bylander/pubs/ml00-final.pdf.